# Wiremock multiple matching for single query parameter

Tags: parameters, matching, wiremock

I am using Wiremock standalone 2.21, and i want to have multiple matches for a single query parameter. 
What I'm sending with postman:

```
http://localhost:8787/template?param1=test1
```

In my mapping file i have this:

```
...

    "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPattern":"/template.*",
        "queryParameters" : {
            "param1" : {
                "equalTo" : "test1"
            }
        }
    },

...
```

I want it to also match with other strings. ex: test2, test3, etc. Is that possible with Wiremock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with this workaround: use "matches" and define a regex instead of "equalTo", like so:

```
      {...
        "request": {
            "method": "POST",
            "urlPattern":"/template.*",
            "queryParameters" : {
                "param1" : {
                    "matches" : "(\\btest1\\b|\\btest2\\b|\\test3\\b)"
                }
            }
        },...
```

This can be unconfortable if you want to have it to match a lot of "test" phrases but works. Normally would be `\btest1\b` but had to escape the `\` with another `\`.